# How can I run this function in a more efficent way?

Tags: python, computer-vision, transformation

I have the following function:

```
def pil_to_latents(dataset):
    '''
    Function to convert image to latents
    '''
    image = [image.convert('RGB').resize((config.image_size, config.image_size)) for image in dataset['train']['image']]
    init_image = [tfms.ToTensor()(ima).unsqueeze(0) * 2.0 - 1.0 for ima in image]
    init_image = [ima.to(device="cuda", dtype=torch.float16) for ima in init_image]
    init_latent_dist = [vae.encode(ima).latent_dist.sample() * 0.18215 for ima in init_image]
    dataset['train']['latents'] = init_latent_dist
    return dataset
```

In each line I'm doing a list comprehension, I would like to do the for loop once and apply all the functions to each image.
I was thinking something like Compose from torchvision should do, but its only for their objects and not for handmade functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple mechanical refactoring:

```
def pil_to_latents(dataset):
    '''
    Function to convert image to latents
    '''
    latents = []
    for img in dataset['train']['image']:
        image = img.convert('RGB').resize((config.image_size, config.image_size))
        ima = tfms.ToTensor()(image).unsqueeze(0) * 2.0 - 1.0
        init_image = ima.to(device="cuda", dtype=torch.float16) 
        init_latent_dist = vae.encode(init_image).latent_dist.sample() * 0.18215
        latents.append(init_latest_dist)
    dataset['train']['latents'] = latents
    return dataset
```